# Delete Multiple Windows Accounts by using CMD

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, user-accounts, user

Is there a way to achive so?
I usually test on my computer different CMD commands with different privileges, so I create many users (I know that I can change the privileges by using net user but I prefer to do so this way).
I was thinking about a variable like %allusers% or something like that to delete all users and create a new only one, like this:

```
net user %allusers% /del & net user "USERNAME" /add
```

or

```
net localgroup users %allusers% /del
```

Basically I want to delete or change privileges from window's users by a variable like %allusers%.

Comment: There isn’t a way to delete multiple user profiles, to delete all users in a user group, you have to loop through each user in the group and delete it.  How you want to do what you want isn’t possible.

Comment: Think about it for moment. If you could delete all users you would remove the currently running user, which is a bad thing :)

Comment: @davidpostill ... For that i'm saying to create a new user after deleting all ...

Comment: @Bita You are missing the point. There must be at least one user (with the appropriate privileges) to create another user. You can never have zero users.

Comment: @davidpostill Yes you can. You can have just one admin user, delete it, and create another, but if you delete the unique admin user it cannot be completely deleted if you do not create other admin account. Knowing that, I want to delete all windows users, and in the same session create other admin user.

Comment: **No**, you can't delete *all* of a machine's accounts. For example, attempting to delete the built-in Administrator account will give you the error *"Cannot perform this operation on built-in accounts."*

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator But is it possible to delete other account, not in which I am logged in, by using a variable? For example: net user %user2% /del

Comment: @Bita unfortunately no. That command only works on one account at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by [TwistyImpersonator](https://superuser.com/users/213131/twisty-impersonator)

**No**, it is not possible to delete multiple accounts or all windows accounts. You have to log into each account deleting them 1 by 1 using the command:

```
Net User "%username%" /DEL
```